# jQuery: Select all INPUT, SELECT elements for given name but exclude hidden types

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got something like that:

```
<form id="my_form">
<input type="hidden" name="name_1" value="1">
<input type="text" name="name_2" value="text_1">
<input type="text" name="name_3" value="text_2">
<select name="name_4">
    <option value="1">opt1</option>
    <option value="2">opt2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

and in my jQuery code:

```
$('#my_form').serializeArray().forEach(function(item){
  // here 'item' has two props: 'name' and 'value'
  // how can I select form's item based on name but NOT type HIDDEN ?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**:not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Change Your selector as

```
$('#my_form :not(:hidden)').serializeArray().forEach(function(item){
  // here 'item' has two props: 'name' and 'value'
  // how can I select form's item based on name but NOT type HIDDEN ?
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/56mZb/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my_form').find("input[type!='hidden']").serializeArray().forEach(function(item){
  // here 'item' has two props: 'name' and 'value'
  // how can I select form's item based on name but NOT type HIDDEN ?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

> Selects all elements that do not match the given selector.

Code:

```
$('#my_form :not([type=hidden])').serializeArray().forEach(function(item){

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5gygs/

Comment: Why not using '.each()' instead of serializeArray?